# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 in Spinner

Tags: java, android

So this error keeps coming up. It happens when I open the spinner. The spinner is in a FragmentDialog, if that can tell you anything about the error.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:448)
                  at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:963)
                  at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:959)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:833)
                  at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(Spinner.java:1194)
                  at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1220)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:758)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:438)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and I've been looking for the source of the problem for two hours now.

here's `addMethod.java` which the adapter works in.

```
public class addMethod extends DialogFragment {
boolean chooseAType = false;
ArrayList<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
String[] names;
public addMethod newInstance(Context context) {


    addMethod fragment = new addMethod();
    fragment.context =context;
    return fragment;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_method_fragment, container);
    getDialog().setTitle("Add payment method.");
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.methodSpinner);
    names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PaymentTypes);
    for(int i = 0;i < names.length;i++){

        paymentMethods.add(new PaymentMethod(names[i],i));

    }
    paymentMethods.add(0,new PaymentMethod("Choose A Country",-1));

    MethodTypesAdapter methodTypesAdapter = new      MethodTypesAdapter(getActivity(),0,paymentMethods);
    spinner.setAdapter(methodTypesAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            chooseAType = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    final TextInputLayout editText = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.addNameInput);
    TextView ok = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    final int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddMethodFeedback addMethodFeedback = (AddMethodFeedback) getActivity();
            if (editText.getEditText().getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 && !chooseAType) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                addMethodFeedback.methodName(editText.getEditText().toString(), pos);
            }
        }
    });
    TextView cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    getDialog().setTitle(getTag());

    return view;
}
}
```

And Heres the `MethodTypesAdapter.java` class.

```
public class MethodTypesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PaymentMethod> {
public MethodTypesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PaymentMethod> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PaymentMethod paymentMethod = getItem(position);
    Utils utils = new Utils(null);

    if (paymentMethod.getType() == -1) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        name.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.chooseAMethod));
    } else {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_with_pic, null, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemsName);
        name.setText(paymentMethod.getName());
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemsIcon);
        icon.setImageResource(utils.methodTypeIcons()[position]);
    }


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use a `Spinner`, you need to [call `setDropDownViewResource()` on your `ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource(int)) (or subclasses like `MethodTypesAdapter`), to provide a layout resource to use for when the spinner is open and showing the scrolling list for the user to select from. So, for example, you could use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` in the `MethodTypesAdapter` constructor and `getView()`, and use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` with `setDropDownViewResource()`.

Comment: Could you provide a code example please for posterity?

Answer (score 4):

To add to CommonsWare's answer:

Alternately if you are using your own custom ArrayAdapter with a Spinner you need to implement/override the `getDropDownView(...)` method as well as the usual `getView(...)` method.

example spinner adapter implementation:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter

class MySpinnerAdapter(context: Context, objects: List<String>) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 0, objects) {
    /**
     * From [android.widget.Adapter]
     *
     * Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data set. You can either
     * create a View manually or inflate it from an XML layout file. When the View is inflated, the
     * parent View (GridView, ListView...) will apply default layout parameters unless you use
     * [android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate]
     * to specify a root view and to prevent attachment to the root.
     *
     * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set of the item whose view
     * we want.
     * @param convertView The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view
     * is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert
     * this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view.
     * Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so that this View is
     * always of the right type (see [getViewTypeCount] and
     * [getItemViewType]).
     * @param parent The parent that this view will eventually be attached to
     * @return A View corresponding to the data at the specified position.
     */
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = TODO("Inflate your view for the 'closed' state of the spinner (this is the selected item view)")
        //todo: set view values...
        return view
    }

    /**
     * From [android.widget.SpinnerAdapter]
     *
     * Gets a [android.view.View] that displays in the drop down popup
     * the data at the specified position in the data set.
     *
     * @param position index of the item whose view we want.
     * @param convertView the old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should
     * check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before
     * using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the
     * correct data, this method can create a new view.
     * @param parent the parent that this view will eventually be attached to
     * @return a [android.view.View] corresponding to the data at the
     * specified position.
     */
    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = TODO("Inflate your view for the 'opened' state of the spinner (this is the dropdown item view)")
        //todo: set view values...
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example please for anyone reading this in the future? For instance, what do I do with `getView`?

Comment: Updated with code implementation example